# How to fetch invoice journal entries from Online Quickbooks app

Tags: odoo, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, invoice

I am trying to import the journal entries against invoice, payment and stock from quickbooks-online app. How can i fetch the same using simple query.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your attempt so far in your question. This website is about helping people with specific problems. If you can show you've made some effort you're more likely to get help.

Comment: Please post your code, and what programming language you're developing in, and what library you're using (Intuit provides libraries for many common programming languages).